# Highcharts: horizontal line the whole width

Tags: javascript, highcharts

How to make a horizontal line the whole width?
[(marked in red)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UEMFQ.png)

Sorry for bad English. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you, please, give a link to your configuration on some site like https://jsfiddle.net/? For example, something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/kh5jY/. It's not easy to give an advice looking on the screenshot.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kh5jY/9391/

Answer (score 0):

You can set `gridLineColor: 'red'` in yAxis option in highchart.

[Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/deep3015/5ombys3o/2/)

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },

    yAxis: {
        gridLineColor: 'red',
        gridLineWidth: 3,/* change width of line*/
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }]
});
```

Comment: You have not understood correctly. I need to do the whole width. I noted how red must be the end result.